# Spark refresh cache table asynchronously

Tags: apache-spark, caching

We have cached tables in Spark Thrift Server. Data is cached on weekly basis:

```
cache table event_2018_12_1 as select * from ... where ...;
cache table event_2018_12_2 as select * from ... where ...;
```

Since we're constantly updating our source data (Cassandra), we need to refresh the cache:

```
refresh table event_2018_12_1;
select count(*) from event_2018_12_1;

refresh table event_2018_12_2;
select count(*) from event_2018_12_2
```

Refresh operation is lazy, so I need to trigger the refresh with `count(*)` operation.

**The problem is when other clients selects data from cached table in the same time its being refreshed** - The select hangs until the cache is fully refreshed (which takes minutes to complete).

I'd like to refresh the cache asynchronously and expose the fresh data only when loading is finished (similar to guava's `LoadingCache` behaviour).

How can I achieve this in Spark ?

**Possible workaround:**

Create a view as layer above the cached tables:

```
create or replace TEMPORARY VIEW event_2018_10 as 
select * from event_2018_12_1
union all select * from event_2018_12_2
```

Instead of refresh just create a new cache and replace the view:

```
cache table event_2018_12_1_c1 as select * from ... where ...;

create or replace TEMPORARY VIEW event_2018_10 as 
select * from event_2018_12_1_c1
union all select * from event_2018_12_2;

--after some delay drop the first cache
drop table event_2018_12_1;
```

I'm concerned about changing the view's DDL and having selects in the same time. Can something go wrong ?